# Drawing a bitmap (ball) onto a polygon with the edges around the ball transparent, on Android using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparent

The game I am writing has two layers. The first is the background layer, which I draw by texturing a background image onto a polygon. The second level has a small polygon (representing a ball) that moves around the screen on top of the background layer.

When I texture a PNG of a ball onto the small polygon (second layer), the texture is drawn, but the rest of the small polygon is black. I want the black behind the ball to be transparent, so that you can see the background behind it. In other words, every pixel on the polygon that is not part of the ball needs to be transparent.

I have experimented with blending, but with no success.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Enable blending when drawing the ball. The ball PNG must have an alpha channel and be transparent at the desired places.

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
draw_background();

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
draw_ball();
```